# How to wipe Chrome OS partition from Dual Booted Acer c720

Tags: partitioning, google-chrome-os, fdisk

Ok, I have a dualbooted Acer c720, with Chrome OS and Gallium OS. Gallium OS supports steam. I have been able to use blender on the Gallium OS partition. However, I want more space for projects. Is there any way that I can run 100% Gallium OS on my Chromebook?(Preferrably deleting it, however anything will do.)
Please help, I'm not familiar with Chrome OS, or Gallium OS ( because of that I may require additional info in accordance to your answer) Thank you!

Comment: if you need more info just ask please

Comment: Going to 3-years-old details will need an enormous answer, which will not happen even with a bounty. The question is whether you are willing to accept that you will also need to make an effort in following an answer or not?

Comment: It's a metaphor. If someone could answer kindly, there is a high probability that I'll need more info. Just a "answerer beware" kinda thing. I will make a few edits to clarify

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing Gallium OS is well documented and I have added below a couple of useful
links. You will need to study well these articles, and the articles they link to,
before coming up with more questions.

**Preparing the boot media**

First, as there are different images for
[different models of Chromebook](https://wiki.galliumos.org/Hardware_Compatibility),
you need to choose the right one for your device.
In your case, the Acer c720 is marked in the "Processor" column as "Intel Haswell".

Now you can download the
[GalliumOS installation ISO image](https://galliumos.org/download)
by clicking on the "Haswell" button.

Once you have the installation image, create a bootable USB drive with it.
The instructions for this are found on the GalliumOS website at
[Installing/Creating Bootable USB](https://wiki.galliumos.org/Installing/Creating_Bootable_USB).

**Backup before installation**

It is best to create a recovery image for your device in case something goes wrong
or if you decide that you want to go back to the current state.

You should create an image of your entire disk as backup, if you have enough
available disk media, for example by using Clonezilla.

**Installing GalliumOS**

Shut down the computer, plug in the USB drive containing the bootable
installation image, and restart, ensuring that the USB is used as the boot media.
The boot menu is entered from the BIOS by pressing
<kbd>F12</kbd> or <kbd>F2</kbd>, per your computer model.

The rest is a normal Linux installation, where the only difference is that you need
to re-format the entire disk as one partition.

References, please study them well before asking questions:

- [Installing - GalliumOS Wiki](https://wiki.galliumos.org/Installing)
- [Installing Galliumos On An Acer Chromebook](https://zgul.de/blog/installing-galliumos)
- [Running Linux on your Chromebook with GalliumOS](https://opensource.com/article/17/4/linux-chromebook-gallium-os)

Comment: How do I get to BIOS

Comment: Normally for Acer this is F2 while booting, but may also be the DEL key.